# Pandas - automate string replacement on dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have this function to find duplicates in a dataframe:

```
def checkForDuplicates():
    database_dup_first = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['name','slug','id'], keep='first')
    df = database_dup_first[database_dup_first.duplicated(['name','id'], keep=False)]
    for index, value in df.iterrows():
        slug = value.slug
        team = value.team
        print ((slug, team))
    
    return df
```

which prints tuples with repeated players (with slightly different name entries) and their teams:

```
df = checkForDuplicates() 

('Wesley', 'Bragantino')
('Wesley Pionteck', 'Bragantino')
('Leonardo Gil', 'Vasco')
('Léo Gil', 'Vasco')
('João Paulo', 'Fortaleza')
('João Paulo Silveira', 'Fortaleza')
...
```

---

Now I need to perform a replacement on the dataset, where the last (always the last) similar entry replaces the first.

I know I could perform this manually, for all returned duplicates, like so:

```
df = checkForDuplicates()

for index, value in df.iterrows():
    slug = value.slug
    team = value.team
    if slug == 'Wesley' and team =='Bragantino':
        df['slug'].iloc[index] = 'Wesley Pionteck'
    if slug == 'Leonardo Gil' and team =='Vasco':
        df['slug'].iloc[index] = 'Léo Gil'   
    if slug == 'João Paulo' and team =='Vasco':
        df['slug'].iloc[index] = 'João Paulo Silveira'
```

---

But the actual list of duplicates is huge. So how can I automate this replacement for all duplicate entries?

Comment: so do you want to replace the following slug with previous slug?

Comment: Yeah that’s it, please

Comment: Is your whole dataset like this or only some rows?

Comment: Actually the following (last, newer) slug should replace the first slug. This is a small subset example. The dataset is huge and has many other cases

Comment: So your whole dataset pattern is like this? Or there is some unique rows in your dataset?

Comment: Mostly unique. But at least a dozen players change name spelling during the year, and that’s what I need to account for

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227570/discussion-between-prakash-dahal-and-8-bit-borges).

Answer (score 1):

Your solution:

```py
n=len(df['slug'])
for i,e in enumerate(df['slug']):
  if i < n-1:
    a = df.iloc[i,0]
    b = df.iloc[i+1,0]
    match_count = 0
    if len(a.split()) < len(b.split()):
      fcount = len(a.split())
    else:
      fcount = len(b.split())
    for a1 in a.split():
      for b1 in b.split():
        if (a1.find(b1)>=0 or b1.find(a1) >=0):
          match_count+=1
          if (match_count == fcount) and (df.iloc[i,1] == df.iloc[i+1,1]):
            match_count = 0
            df.iloc[i,0] = df.iloc[i+1,0]
  else:
    break
```

Comment: thank you very much. is your `df`above the one returned by the function `checkForDuplicates()`?

Comment: I have slightly modified the code. Now it will also check the value of team column is matching or not :)

Comment: Thanks again. I cannot test your solution as of now, but i can tell  you that it breaks the code and generates some inf values in the dataframe. The conditions in my manual solution are somewhat important so as not to mess with the wrong rows

Comment: Hi, I am not aware of your full dataset but this should work for the pattern you have mentioned in the question. I have checked by adding and removing new duplicate and unique values.

Answer (score 0):

```
# keep the last slug with unique name and id
df_slug_last = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['name','id'], keep='last')[['name','slug','id']]
df_slug_last.columns = ['name','slug_last','id']

# merge the last slug to the origin df
dfn = pd.merge(df, df_slug_last, on=['name','id'], how='left')
```

`dfn['slug_last']` will be the lastest slug for every unique name,id